# Anyone Added Custom Field in to Task List Show into Dashboard (Phabricator)

Tags: php, project-management, phabricator

I have added due_date into the Manifest Custom Field. Now I want that where ever task list showing to the user then Due Date also displayed over there.
I know its very small change in codebase but I am not able to debug this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed a step you need I think to call `$fields->readFieldsFromStoage($task)` and then I used `$field->getValueForStorage()`

I can't say how correct or legal, of even efficient it is, but it does what I think you wanted

```
 $fields = PhabricatorCustomField::getObjectFields(
              $task,PhabricatorCustomField::ROLE_VIEW);    

if ($fields){ 
        $fields->readFieldsFromStorage($task);
        foreach ($fields->getFields() as $field){
           if ($field->getModernFieldKey()=='custom.mycustomfield'){
                      // in theory you might be able to add it like this
                      $item->addByline(pht('Due Date:%s', $field->getValueForStorage()));
                      $item->addByline(pht('Assigned: %s', $owner->renderLink()));
           }
        }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hats Of to You, Bro :) It will Help Number of People Who are using Phabricator. Guys Its working well. Only thing you need to format date which is INT field in mysql. You need to convert it into your usable format.  like this $item->addByline(pht('Due Date:%s', date("d-M-Y H:i:s", $field->getValueForStorage())));

Answer (score 1):

Ok not a solution, but a place to start...

To alter this you need to edit

ManiphestTaskListView.php in

phabricator/src/applications/maniphest/view

Where you want to put due date is where "Assigned:" is put

```
  if ($task->getOwnerPHID()) {
    $owner = $handles[$task->getOwnerPHID()];
    $item->addByline(pht('Assigned: %s', $owner->renderLink()));
  }
```

Pulling in the custom fields may require a little more research, I think you can get to the tasks custom fields via the following

```
 $fields = PhabricatorCustomField::getObjectFields(
              $task,PhabricatorCustomField::ROLE_VIEW);
```

You could then pull out the field you want like this if you have to, I suspect there is a better way of doing this...so you just ask for the specific field

```
  if ($fields){
                foreach ($fields->getFields() as $field){
                   if ($field->getModernFieldKey()=='custom.mycustomfield'){
                         // in theory you might be able to add it like this
                         $item->addByline(pht('%s', $field->getXXXX()));
                   }
  }
```

I'm not sure what you need to do to get the custom field value, i'm using getXXXX() to represent the sort of thing you might need to do, I think the custom fields often have a render() method but again I'm not completely sure how you go about getting that to render in your listview

Comment: But I am Not able to get value of this field {
  "mytask.due-date": {
    "name": "Due Date",
    "type": "date",
    "required": "true",
    "caption": "Due Date For This Task"
  }
}

Comment: Can you please help me. Its working fine till the field list? somehow i am not able to print the value of the field.